# Как адресовать функцию к каждому элементу списка БД?

Tags: c, visual-studio, список

Есть БД в виде структуры, и отдельно структура указателей, так что действия осуществляются не с самими элементами, а с указателями на них. Вот обе структуры

```
typedef struct {
    int num;
    char name[20];
    struct tm date;
} record;

typedef struct _list {
    record d;
    struct _list *next;
} list_;
```

Соответственно функции работают уже с указателями

```
void print_rec(record * r)
{
    printf("%d,%s,%02d/%02d/%04dn", r->num, r->name, r->date.tm_mday, r - >date.tm_mon + 1, r->date.tm_year + 1900);
}
```

Вопрос - как адресовать функцию любому элементу списка, чтобы печатался список независимо от длины. Сейчас, когда я вывожу первый элемент,

```
print_rec(&p->d);
```

второй

```
print_rec(&p->next->d);
```

понимаю, что поэлементно указывать в корне неверно, а как написать общий случай не пойму. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Дополнение:
первое что пришло в голову конечно циклы

```
     for (r=&p->d;p->next!=0;p=p->next){print_rec(r)}
```

или

```
       while(p=p->next!=0)
    {print_rec(&p->d);
    p=p->next;}
```

но не работет почему то, выводит только первый или второй элемент(причем столько раз сколько реально элементов в списке)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в p указатель на первый элемент списка, то просмотр всего списка:

```
struct _list *p;
...
while (p) {
    print_rec (&p->d);
    p = p->next;
}
```

Вы реньше времени присваиваете p указатель на следующий элемент.

PS. Аббревиатура **БД** в заголовке вопроса (и метка база-данных) обычно ассоциируется с СУБД, что в данном случае не совсем корректно (попросту сбивает потенциально отвечающего с толку). Вопрос-то ведь о программировании связных списков на C.

Comment: да,простите,учту!вся голова забита составлением этой базы))

спасибо огромное!!!прекрасно работает!!!!